# VS 2013 can't add existing project to TFS source control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a solution with 4 projects and it's bond with TFS source control. I then add an existing project to that solution and I checked-in, then VS 2013 added all the new files to source control but it seems to ignore the newly added project:
[image]

The newly added project is HRP_PAIE (you can see it doesn't have the lock next to its' name). This create a problem when another member of my team tries to get the latest version: He doesn't get the HRP_PAIE project.

Please help

Comment: Right click on the project and select "Add to Source Control" and check-in

Comment: @KishoreSahas Warning: No pending changes. Btw that's what I did the first time I checked in

Comment: have you checked the "Source Control Explorer" for these files ?

Comment: Yes the files are there, my problem is that the new project is not considered as a project, so when someone else gets the latest version the source control doesn't know where to put those files

Comment: to restore the binding in VS 2010, go to File->Source Control->Change Source Control. Look for the "Solution: your solution name" and if it's not bound it will say "no server". Click on it and then click "Bind" from the toolbar.

in Visual Studio 2012/2013 it's File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control

Answer (score 6):

To solve this problem, this is what I did: 
1. Open Source control explorer 
2. Right click on the folder
3. Select "Add Items to folder"
The "Add to Source Control" window will pop up
4. Add the items you want to add

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good to know :)

Comment: If you select the folder that the project is in, this works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `File->Source Control->Change Source Control.`
(in Visual Studio 2012/2013 it's `File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control)`

Look for the "Solution: your solution name" and if it's not bound it will say "no server". Click on it and then click "Bind" from the toolbar.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not

Comment: could you please share a screenshot of the  `File->Source Control->Change Source Control` dialog

Comment: Sorry didn't had the time to do all that ! I created a new solution and added all the projects and then bound it to source control, now it's fine.

Comment: There is no option called "Change Source Control" under the "Source Control" submenu of the "File" menu in my installation of VS 2010.  Anyone have a clue why that is?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the really late response; however, hoping to solve the issue for someone who is passing by on the highway of Google:

Go to File->Source Control->Change Source Control. (in Visual Studio 2012/2013 it's File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control)

Look for the "Solution: your solution name", highlight it and click Unbind. Hit Okay, then right click on the project in solution explorer, hover over source control and click add project to source control!

Comment: There is no "Change Source Control" option under File->Source Control menu in VIsual Studio 2010...